# Why is a floor texture applying to the outside/inside walls of a cube instead of the selected floor?

Tags: rendering, uv

Previously I was able to get a different downloaded floor diffused/normal/roughness/specular.PNG to apply correctly to the same cube room but to out of the three demonstrate this outside/inside wall and ceiling issue as mentioned in my question, can anybody tell me how to correct this and why this applies in certain cases?
I will attach images of the wire , materials, vector and relevant UV and shader editor view's.
[image]

Comment: You have to assign different materials for the different parts.

Comment: OK thanks, just added repeat of the same texture and deleted the first textures you can see below and that worked thanks